# How to terminate HttpWebRequest Connection in C#?It doesn't work even set timeout or readwritetimeout

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, timeout

I want to terminate a httpwebrequest when it takes too long time in connection.
Here is just a simaple code that I wrote:

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.Timeout = 5000;
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = 5000;
            request.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://" + proxyUsed + "/", true);
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.01; Windows NT 5.0)";

            using (WebResponse myResponse = request.GetResponse())
            {                    
                using (Stream s = myResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    s.ReadTimeout = 5000;
                    s.WriteTimeout = 5000;
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                    {                            
                        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        httpLink = myResponse.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;
                        sr.Close();
                    }
                    s.Close();
                }
                myResponse.Close();
            }
```

However, sometimes the connection will take a about 15minutes to get the response.
The situation is after 15minutes I still can get the response but not the full source code of the URL.
I guess that the connection is too slow that the URL response me a bit data within the timeout, just say for example receive 1byte in 5seconds, so it doesn't expire the timoue but it's very long.
How can I terminate the connection?
Thanks:)

Answer (score 6):

You might find that the timeout is actually working, but the thread hangs when trying to close the stream. I don't know why it happens, but sometimes it does. I've never used `ReadToEnd`, but I've run across this when using `Read`.

I fixed the problem by calling `Abort` on the request, before I close the stream. It's a bit of a kluge, but it's effective. The abbreviated code below shows the technique.

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;
StreamReader sr = null;
try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(...);
    Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
    sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.UTF8);
    // do your reading here
}
finally
{
    request.Abort();  // !! Yes, abort the request
    if (sr != null)
        sr.Dispose();
    if (response != null)
        response.Close();
}
```

What I've found is that the `ReadTimeout` and `ReadWriteTimeout` work as expected. That is, when the read times out, execution really does go to the `finally` block. And if the `request.Abort` isn't there, the call to `sr.Dispose` will hang.

Answer (score 2):

Break down the stream reading, and abort if the total time has been too long.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Timeout = 5000;
request.ReadWriteTimeout = 5000;
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://" + proxyUsed + "/", true);
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.01; Windows NT 5.0)";//ahem! :)
DateTime giveUp = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(5); 
using (WebResponse myResponse = request.GetResponse())
{                    
    httpLink = myResponse.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;
    using (Stream s = myResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        s.ReadTimeout = 5000;
        s.WriteTimeout = 5000;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
        {                            
            for(int read = sr.Read(buffer, 0, 4096); read != 0; read = sr.Read(buffer, 0, 4096))
            {
                if(DateTime.UtcNow > giveUp)
                    throw new TimeoutException();
                sb.Append(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            result = sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to also close the connection on exception. In that case the WebResponse object is on the WebException:

```
try
{
    using (WebResponse myResponse = request.GetResponse())
      // do stuff
}
catch (WebException webEx)
{
    webEx.Response.Close();
}
```