# HttpWebRequest timeout not obeyed

Tags: c#, asp.net, timeout, httpwebrequest

I have set up the following web request:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(gotoWebinerUrl);
request.Accept = "text/json";
request.Timeout = 5000;

// Allows us to track with Fiddler, for dev use only
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);

try
{
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    ...
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    ...
}
```

In Fiddler, I have installed this plugin which delays requests http://fiddlerdelayext.codeplex.com/. Using the plugin, I have added a rule which delays the webinar request URL by 60,000ms (1 min).

I would expect my application to delay for 5 seconds, fail and be caught by my exception. However, it delays for the full 60 seconds.

I'm not sure if this is the plugins problem or my application, but I suspect the latter. In the 60 seconds delay, I can navigate to other web pages and see the requests in Fiddler, so I don't believe the problem exists with the plugin.

I found a couple of similar questions ([How to terminate HttpWebRequest Connection in C#?It doesn't work even set timeout or readwritetimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816431/how-to-terminate-httpwebrequest-connection-in-cit-doesnt-work-even-set-timeou)), but I'm not very familiar with threads and if they apply here or not.

**Additional Info**

A bit more research into this stepping through the code and I've noticed some interesting behaviour. The `GetResponse` is fired successfully and I see the request made in Fiddler. I then have my 60 seconds wait time. However, when I can continue stepping through, I notice that it has been caught as a `TimeoutException`, despite the fact it's actually waited the full 60s and has received a successful response. This does suggest that maybe something in the plugin is fooling the application into holding on somehow.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but my first thought would be instead of using the Fiddler plugin to maybe stall the actual web response on the web server.  For example in your ASP.net code you could throw in a `Thread.Sleep(60000)` call.  This way your artificial stall is in the actual generation of the web response and not in some middle man proxy server, or worse a plugin to a middle man proxy server.  I think you have too may variables involved here to accomplish what you are trying to do.   Doing it as I've stated brings this closer to how things would actually happen in the real world.